# Verification of my solution of $xy'=2y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given:

\begin{equation}xy'=2y\end{equation}

Therefore,

\begin{equation}y'=(2y)/x\end{equation}

Solving for y, I have:

$y=Cx^2$ (Originally, was $e^cx^2$, but C is arbitrary, so I simplified)

To start verifying the solution, I inserted y' into the original equation:

\begin{equation}x(\frac{2y}{x})=2y\end{equation}

Next, I substitute the value of y:
\begin{equation}x(\frac{2Cx^2}{x})=2(Cx^2)\end{equation}

After simplifying both sides, I have:

\begin{equation}2Cx^2=2Cx^2\end{equation}

Did I do this right?

Thanks!

Comment: use [solution-verification] or [proof-verification] tag for this kind of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $y=Cx^2$.  That means $y'=2Cx$.  Let's plug those in to your original differential equation
$$xy'=2y.$$
That is
$$x(2Cx)=2(Cx^2)$$
which reduces to
$$2Cx^2=2Cx^2$$
which verifies that you have the correct solution.

Answer (score 4):

Right solution, wrong verification.
you have to get $y'=2Cx$ from your final solution and then substitute to get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

What you "verified" is that, if $y'=2y/x$ and if $y=Cx^2$ then $xy'=2y$. Since the condition $y'=2y/x$ alone implies that $xy'=2y$ this is not a verification at all.

Rather, assume that $y=Cx^2$. Then $y'=2Cx$ hence $xy'-2y=x(2Cx)-2(Cx^2)=0$, that is, $xy'=2y$.

To sum up, one is supposed to check that, if $y=Cx^2$ then $y$ solves the equation $xy'=2y$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the derivative of y first before you can verify your equation.

$y = Cx^2$

$y' = C(2x) +x^2(0) = 2xC$

Recall that your equation is

$\begin{equation}xy'=2y\end{equation}$

now substitute the result from $y'$ and the original $y$

$\begin{equation}xy'=2y\end{equation}$

$\begin{equation}x(2xC)=2(Cx^2)\end{equation}$

$\begin{equation}(2x^2C)=2(Cx^2)\end{equation}$